# XS Vulnerability - Failed.XSS Patch not detected (APPSEC-1716)

Tags: magento2

I have checked magento security scan and i am getting the failed patch. can any one please let me know . How to fix this and how to apply patch . is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Priya, I am also getting the same issue. Did you find solution for this?

Comment: No @BalwantSingh. We have to  get the patch from magento store and we have to apply for that.